# Jquery clone div breaking events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am cloning a `div` and changing all of the child element `id's` and appending it below the original `div`. Now within that `div` I have several buttons that trigger events when clicked. Each one of these buttons have a `class` name that I am using to fire the event opposed to using the `id`. However when I try to click on any buttons within my cloned `div` none of my events are firing.

Here is how I am cloning my `div`, changing the `id's` and appending it:

```
$(function() {    
  var $section = $("#facility_section_info").clone();
  var $cloneID = 1; 
    $( ".addSection" ).click(function() { 
        var $sectionClone = $section.clone(true).find("*[id]").andSelf().each(function() { $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + $cloneID); });
        $('#facility_section_info').append($sectionClone);
        $cloneID++; 
    });
});
```

here is an original uncloned button within the div that fires an event.

```
<input type="button" value="+" id="addRows" class="addRows"/>
```

And here is what the cloned button looks like:

```
<input type="button" value="+" id="addRows1" class="addRows">
```

The only thing that has changed is that I have added a 1 at the end of the `id`.

Here is the event that gets fired when this button gets clicked:

```
$(function() {
    var $componentTB = $("#component_tb"),
        $firstTRCopy = $("#row0").clone();
        $idVal = 1;
    $(".addRows").click(function() {
        var copy = $firstTRCopy.clone();
        var newId = 'row' +$idVal;
        copy.attr('id', newId);
        $idVal += 1;
        copy.children('td').last().append("<a href=\"javascript:remove('" + newId + "')\">Remove</a>");
        $componentTB.append(copy);
    });
});
```

All this function does is clone a table row in its original form and append it to the end of a table with an added remove link. This function works exactly how I need it to other than not firing when I click on my cloned button.

Why do my cloned buttons not fire any of my events that are called by `class` name and not `id`?

Comment: binding the events may be ....   use .on to bind the events and see if works!

Comment: @Kalish if you read my question you will notice that I am doing exactly that already.

Comment: And the downvote was for....?

Comment: I can't see you are using .on to bind the events!!

Comment: @Kalish `.click()` is shortcut for `.on("click")`

Comment: well, there is a significance difference in the usage pattern .... see this for more information....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click

Comment: @Kalish we are talking about `$(".addRows").click(function() {` and `$(".addRows").on("click", function() {`, which are just the same. You can use `.click()` to trigger events and `.on()` for delegated event handlers, but this is not we are talking about. My answer was to your phrase _I can't see you are using .on to bind the events!_

Comment: @Regent - well, I think we both are on the same page! .click() and .on('click') are same but to answer this question, both are not same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest answer; the clone isn't breaking the event. The event isn't firing because it's never assigned to the new element. What you're doing when you `clone` the element is creating a *dynamic* element. This means it's added to the DOM after the page has loaded, at which point, your event was already delegated.

The way you're delegating the event is not wrong. It's simply not the best practice when you will have *dynamic elements*. There are a few ways you can handle this.

> Using `.clone()`'s *withDataAndEvents* parameter.

The *withDataAndEvents* parameter of `.clone()` is intended to make this process easier by copying data and events to the new element, as such

```
var copy = $firstTRCopy.clone(true)
```

However, this can have a few nasty side-effects. For instance, it's been known to clone `id`'s and if your event is assigned to an `id`, you'll still only get `fire` on the first element.

> [Event Delegation](https://api.jquery.com/on/) - See [*Understanding Event Delegation*](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

This is a method by which we use a `parent element`, or even the `document root` Object to attach events that will always be fired on all children. Such as:

```
$(document).on('click', '.addRow', function(e) {...})
```

Due to convenience more than anything, it's often not recommended you attach to the `document root`. I had first suggested it because I was in public and it was a quick and easy answer. It's not *unsafe* to attach to the `document root`, but can become an issue if you have a lot going on in your page. See, each element an event is assigned to will *bubble* up when the event is fired. Simply put, when you attach 'click' to an element with an event delegated via the `document`, you're essentially clicking the entire DOM. More often than not, it's not really an issue and I make use of it all day long for convenience of readability.

However, the more proper way would be to look for the closest *parent* element that **exist on load**. That is to say, it is **not** created dynamically. Simply put, like so:

```
    $('#parentAlreadyLoaded').on('click', '.addRow', function(e) {...})
```

> *Note*: Assigning an event to `.addRow` using `$(document)` or `$('parent element selector')` does **not** change the event parameter in `function(e) {`. The `e` in `$('.addRow').click` is the same as the `e` in `$(document OR 'parent').on('click', '.addRow'`

### Short Example

```js
function addRow(e) {
    if (console && console['log']) console.log(e);
 var par = $('#addRows'),
  tr = $('<tr />').appendTo(par),
  tdBlue = $('<td />').appendTo(tr),
  tdRed = $('<td />').appendTo(tr),
  btnBlue = $('<button />', { 'class': 'make-blue', 'text': 'Make Blue' }).appendTo(tdBlue),
  btnRed = $('<button />', { 'class': 'make-red', 'text': 'Make Red' }).appendTo(tdRed)
}

$(function() {
 $('thead button').on('click', addRow);
 $('#addRows').on('click', '.make-blue', function(e) {
        if (console && console['log']) console.log(e);
  $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
 });
 $(document).on('click', '.make-red', function(e) {
        if (console && console['log']) console.log(e);
  $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('blue').addClass('red');
 });
})
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0 auto; }
tr { padding: .25em .5em; text-align: center; }
th, td { border: 3px groove; }
th button { margin: .25em auto; }
td button { margin: .5em; }
.blue { background-color: #00F; }
.red { background-color: #F00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th colspan="2">
            <button>Click Me</button>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="addRows"></tbody>
</table>
```

### Also

Making use of `$(document).on`, as aforementioned is handy for *readability*. For example, If I have a simple page, with 20 or less events and none are really overlapping, then I'll use it to assign events as such:

```
$(document)
    .on('event', 'selector1', function(e) { /*  do Work */ })
    .on('differentEvent', 'selector1', function(e) { /* do Work */ })
    .on('event', 'selector2', function(e) { /*  do Work */ })
    .on('event', 'selector3', function(e) { /*  do Work */ })
    .on('differentEvent', 'selector3', function(e) { /* do Work */ })
    .on('differentEvent2', 'selector3', function(e) { /*    do Work */ })
```

This is possible due to jQuery's *chainability*. Just be careful doing this as you made to use `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent bubbling.

Comment: Why should I do this?

Comment: To assign the event to dynamic elements

Comment: @BigRabbit here you go: [docs](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Comment: @Regent thanks, so would it be safe to always delegate events instead of having them direct?

Comment: @BigRabbit it's not about safety but about purpose of usage :) If element is created dynamically, you can use delegated event handler or you can add event handler after element is inserted into DOM.

Comment: @BigRabbit was in public and in a hurry with previous answer, now it's been updated with a lot more detail. feel free to ask me anything about it

Comment: @SpYk3HH Thats awesome that makes a lot more sense to me now thanks so much. My only confusion now is will I have to change anything within my event if I am taking in a parameter `(e)`, into my function or ..?

Comment: @BigRabbit I added an example. Also, to answer your question, if I think I know what you mean, *no*. In *event delegation*, the parameter `e` or `event` is still the same as always. I'll add to answer real quick

Comment: @BigRabbit Not a problem. I added a little more to the answer, just to try and give you a little more understanding of the usefulness of this type of delegation.

Comment: @SpYk3HH yeah that helps for sure, very interesting and clean.  I wish all these people upvoted this answer instead! ;)

Answer (score 3):

jquery clone method has one parameter "withDataAndEvents" you need to pass true 
like this

```
var copy = $firstTRCopy.clone(true);
```

https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 2):

Your events aren't firing because the handlers are set before you do the cloning. You need to use event delegation.

Instead of this:

```
$(".addRows").click(
```

do this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".addRows",
```